# Unable to use scatter plot in Basemap

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I'm following the tutorial [*Visualization: Mapping Global Earthquake Activity*](http://introtopython.org/visualization_earthquakes.html) to get more familiar with Basemap.

What I'm trying to do is scatter plot the data in a Pandas DataFrame on the the map.

Initialization code for my map:

```
my_map = Basemap(projection='merc', 
                 lat_0=50.93, lon_0=4.13,
                 llcrnrlat=49.339950, llcrnrlon=1.777668,
                 urcrnrlat=51.601360, urcrnrlon=6.925303,
                 resolution='h', area_thresh=1.0)

my_map.drawcoastlines()
my_map.drawcountries()
my_map.fillcontinents(color='coral')
my_map.drawmapboundary()
```

So far so good. Now for the actual data. The structure of my df looks like this:

```
lat    float64
lon    float64
id       int64
dtype: object
```

Sample:

```
|      |     lat |     lon |   id |
|-----:|--------:|--------:|-----:|
| 1083 | 51.8205 | 4.62573 |    7 |
|  211 | 50.5155 | 3.89612 |    1 |
|   89 | 50.3397 | 4.61034 |    1 |
```

The `id` columns is actually a count (the df is an aggregation of a more detailed df). The value in the `id` column should be used to define the marker size.

I started with this simple plot (not yet a scatter plot), which works.

```
x,y = my_map(df_loc.lon.tolist(), df_loc.lat.tolist())
my_map.plot(x, y, 'bo', markersize=10)
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot]

Because I want the marker size to be dependant of the count (i.e. the `id` column), I need to switch from `plot` to `scatter`.

If I try: `my_map.scatter(x, y, s=10)` (i.e. with a fixed size), the result will be an empty map (no points are drawn).

I would appreciate if you could tell me what I'm doing wrong. The strange thing is, a regular scatter plot works just fine (maybe a bad comparison, but still):

```
plt.scatter(df_loc.lon, df_loc.lat, s=df_loc.id, alpha=.3)
plt.ylim(49.339950, 51.601360)
plt.xlim(1.777668, 6.925303)
```

[image: scatter]

**Extra credit:**

From what I've read in the documentation, the additional step of converting lat/lon to map projection should be unnecessary if the `latlon=True` parameter is specified.

> If latlon keyword is set to True, x,y are intrepreted as longitude and
>   latitude in degrees. Data and longitudes are automatically shifted to
>   match map projection region for cylindrical and pseudocylindrical
>   projections, and x,y are transformed to map projection coordinates.

However, if I change this:

```
x,y = my_map(df_loc.lon.tolist(), df_loc.lat.tolist())
my_map.plot(x, y, 'bo', markersize=10)
```

to this:

```
my_map.plot(df_loc.lon, df_loc.lat, 'bo', latlon=True)
```

I end up with the error:

```
SystemError: <class 'RuntimeError'> returned a result with an error set
```

Is this not what the `latlon` parameter is supposed to be used for?

**Update:**

It seems that the `plot` function doesn't like to have Pandas Series objects passed into it as `x` and `y` arguments. This code does work however (difference is the additional `tolist()` call):

```
my_map.plot(df_loc.lon.tolist(), 
            df_loc.lat.tolist(), 
            'bo', 
            latlon=True)
```

Comment: For the second part, do you just miss the `tolist()` in your second command, i.e. `my_map.plot(df_loc.lon.tolist(), df_loc.lat.tolist(), 'bo', latlon=True)`?

Comment: @ThomasKühn Indeed that seems to work. I'll update the OP

Comment: For the first part, what if you try `x,y = my_map(df_loc.lon.tolist(), df_loc.lat.tolist())` and then `plt.scatter(x, y, s=df_loc.id, alpha=.3)`?

Comment: @ThomasKühn Alas, that gives the same result (just the map rendered, not the points).

Comment: Ok, what happens if you leave out `fillcontinents`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with the `zorder`. Specifically, that the `fillcontinents` zorder is greater than that of the `scatter` points, so the scatter points are ending up beneath the fill for the continents (and thus are not visible).

Two ways to fix this:

1. Reduce the `fillcontinents` zorder:

   ```
   my_map.fillcontinents(color='coral', zorder=0)
   ```
2. Increase the `scatter` zorder:

   ```
   my_map.scatter(x, y, s=10, zorder=10)
   ```

Comment: Spot on! Thank you.